# Why do I keep getting a "list indices must be integers or slices, not str"?

Tags: python

I keep getting a "list indices must be integers or slices, not str" when I run this function, and Im not sure why. This function takes an equation and splits it by number and operator
ie: 1+8-9 = ['1','+','8','-','9']

```
def trimFunction(p):
    list = re.split("([+ -])", p)
    if list[0] == '':
        list.remove('')
        
    counter = 0
    for x in list:
#the error happens here vvvv
        if list[x].isnumeric(): 
            counter += 1
    return list, counter
```

Comment: Besides the problem of "don't override Python's built-ins", you can try printing out the values of `x` and you should be able to tell what the problem is.

Comment: Show us the full error traceback!

Answer (score 3):

Because you are iterating over each item in a list which is a string.

`x` in your loop `for x in list` with given `['1','+','8','-','9']` is '1', '+', '8', '-', '9', not the index of them (0, 1, 2, 3, 4).

So your loop should be:

```
for x in list:
    if x.isnumeric():
        counter += 1
return list, counter
```

or

```
for index in range(len(list)):
    if list[index].isnumeric():
        counter += 1
return list, counter
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to x.isnumeric() inplace of list[x].isnumeric()

```
import re
def trimFunction(p):
    list = re.split("([+ -])", p)
    print(list)
    if list[0] == '':
        list.remove('')
    counter = 0
    for x in list:
#Correction
        if x.isnumeric(): 
            counter += 1
    return list, counter 
trimFunction('1+8-9')
```

**OUTPUT**
(['1', '+', '8', '-', '9'], 3)